# Garuda Sannidhi in Kanchipuram Varadaraja Temple

Tags: vishnu, sri-vaishnava, garuda

In most Vishnu temples, there will be a sannidhi for Garuda facing the Moolavar. In Varadaraja temple in Kanchipuram, there is a Garuda sanndhi for Narasimha shrine, but not for Varadaraja shrine which is *atop* the Narasimha shrine. If Varadaraja shrine is on a small hillock as opposed to *first floor* of the temple and if Narasimha shrine is at the foot of hillock as discussed [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-idol-of-Varadharaja-Perumal-in-Kanchipuram-on-the-first-floor-of-the-temple-Why) then both shrines are different. Then why is there no Garuda sannidhi for Varadaraja shrine?